# x3650t ibm hard disk error how to check logs

Tags: hard-drive, ibm, logging

There is a Led indicator on the front panel of IBM x3650T series, 
it is blinking lights, most probably there is a Hard disk error but  need to be sure...
anyone knows how to check the logs on server to ensure this is HDD error

Regards

Answer (score 1):

- If your system is hung and doesn't boot you can view the POST logs in
  BIOS. For that press "F1" at boot and go to the "System event logs"
  option.
- If you want to check the logs while your system is up and running you
  have to login to the IMM. You open the IMM IP in a browser, login with your credentials and then go to the "Event log" page.

There are some other ways too, but these are the most basic / direct.

Some machines also have a big sticker on top of the box that explains some basic error "led blinking", and as always, the manual is your friend...